# I cannot change the gantt bar label

Tags: pgfgantt

I want the style of the bar label to have the same effect of first or second line title , I tried many methods, they all didn't work, please see the bold section(** **) of the codes.
**\ganttset{bar label/.append style=%canvas/.style={draw=none},
    {fill=olive!20, rounded corners=2mm}}**%
**\ganttbar[bar label/.style={fill=olive!20, rounded corners=2mm}]**

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[LoadFandol]{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\makeatletter
\ganttset{title/.append style=%canvas/.style={draw=none},
{fill=blue!20, rounded corners=2mm}}%, drop shadow
**\ganttset{bar label/.append style=%canvas/.style={draw=none},
{fill=olive!20, rounded corners=2mm}}**%, drop shadow
\makeatother
\begin{document}
     \begin{ganttchart}[
     x unit = 0.3cm, 
     y unit title=0.5cm,
     y unit chart=0.7cm,
     vgrid={*{2}{gray!60, dashed}, *1{black}}, 
     hgrid,
     title height=1,
     title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
     bar label font=\color{olive},
     bar/.append style={fill=lime},
     bar label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
       ]{1}{39}
          \gantttitle[]{2016}{12}
      \gantttitle[]{2017}{27}\\
       \gantttitlelist[
        title/.style={inner color=red,rounded corners=2mm}%draw=none,
        ]{9,...,12,1,2,...,9}{3} \\
           **\ganttbar[bar label/.style={fill=olive!20, rounded corners=2mm}]**{一}{1}{24} \\
        \ganttbar{二}{19}{21} \\
        \ganttbar{三}{22}{24} \\
        \ganttbar{四}{22}{27} 
       \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to adjust the bar label position of vertical alignment?
How to zoom the title of second line to fit the table size?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm probably an idiot, but I don't quite understand any of your questions. Can you try explaining more thoroughly exactly what you want to do?

Comment: please see the ** section of the codes, they didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you now ask after the edit, seems to be entirely unrelated to the two questions you asked originally, which I still don't understand.

But to answer the new question, you want to modify the `bar label node` style I think, not the `bar label` style.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\ganttset{title/.append style=%canvas/.style={draw=none},
{fill=blue!20, rounded corners=2mm}}%, drop shadow

\begin{document}
     \begin{ganttchart}[
     x unit = 0.3cm, 
     y unit title=0.5cm,
     y unit chart=0.7cm,
     vgrid={*{2}{gray!60, dashed}, *1{black}}, 
     hgrid,
     title height=1,
     title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
     bar label font=\color{olive},
     bar/.append style={fill=lime},
     bar label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
     bar label node/.append style={fill=olive!20, rounded corners=2mm} %% <--- this one
       ]{1}{39}
      \gantttitle[]{2016}{12}
      \gantttitle[]{2017}{27}\\
      \gantttitlelist[
        title/.style={inner color=red,rounded corners=2mm}%draw=none,
        ]{9,...,12,1,2,...,9}{3} \\

        \ganttbar{A}{1}{24} \\
        \ganttbar{B}{19}{21} \\
        \ganttbar{C}{22}{24} \\
        \ganttbar{D}{22}{27} 
       \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please forgive my terrible English. You are right. I can not distinguish the bar label and bar label node.